# SipML5 and Asterisk returning 488 in makeCall

Tags: asterisk, webrtc, codec, sipml

Trying to make a videoaudio call with SipML5 and Asterisk13, one user in Chorme and the other Firefox, but right after "Ringing"(180) the caller receives "Not acceptable here"(488).
Asterisk messages:

`[Jan 23 11:38:27] NOTICE[11127][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: Received AVP profile in audio answer but AVPF is enabled, disabling: audio 36436 RTP/AVP 111 8 0 101
[Jan 23 11:38:27] WARNING[11127][C-00000004] chan_sip.c: We are requesting SRTP for audio, but they responded without it!`

So about the 488 I found in several pages:

> 488 Not Acceptable Here - 
>   The response has the same meaning as 606 (Not Acceptable), but only applies to the specific resource addressed by the Request-URI and the request may succeed elsewhere.
>   A message body containing a description of media capabilities MAY be present in the response, which is formatted according to the Accept header field in the INVITE (or application/sdp if not present), the same as a message body in a 200 (OK) response to an OPTIONS request.

and

> You have not enabled AVPF support in the peer, user, or friend entry using "avpf=yes" or have not allowed a codec that is supported by the caller.

but I did't found anywhere a way to fix this. Yep, noob in SIP.
The best i tried was to change my peer in sip.conf (add the avpf=true), but not even the asterisk messages changed.

Is it a codec problem? If so, how do I change for one that works in this case?
If not, whats going on here? Kinda loosing my mind already. ^^"

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry but I got no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, Asterisk is following the RFC's and you need to use SAVP / SAVPF profiles when negotiating secure SRTP sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ^^. I searched for SRTP in asterisk(https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling+Tutorial), but no luck. Do you know where i can find a way to do that (use SAVP in asterisk?)